# Flutter: how to get ajax response in webview?

Tags: flutter

I'm use webview for application login and want to get login response ajax.
I use [Webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter), that have:

```
currentUrl
canGoBack
canGoForward
goBack
goForward
reload
```

no feature get ajax response

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I did it,
use JavascriptChannel  webview_flutter: ^0.3.14+1

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'http://your_server',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
        JavascriptChannel(name: 'Print', onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage msg) { 
          print(msg.message); 
          }), ].toSet(),
    );

  }
```

on website(`http://your_server`):

```
<script>
Print.postMessage('Hello!');
</script>
```

use `Print.postMessage('result');` in ajax response